# CakePHP HABTM add tags to post - won't update join table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have Cakephp 2.x app.  It is simple photo gallery app. I want to add one or more new tags to existing photos. Ideally, I want to be able to remove tags from a photo too.

Cakephp HABTM seems to be made for this and promises to do all of this.

I used a standard baked Edit Photo Form view and controller action, with the addition of a tag list as checkboxes that is populated by controller list.

This works well to view all existing tags for that photo.  When I navigate to */app/photos/addtags/id*  the Edit Photo Form populates with that photo id's photo details, and a full list of available tags each with checkbox, and any previously selected tags are checked.

So far so good, but my problem is if I check a new tag and then click submit, it doesn't update photos_tag join table and instead it just adds a new record to photo table.

This is completely unexpected behaviour. I would expect it to only add new record(s) with photo_id and tag_id for new tags to photos_tag  join table.

I know there are a bunch of similar SO questions and I've been to all of them here SO and elsewhere and from what I can tell my tables, models, controller and view are set up properly.

I need help with suggestions on why it isn't working as desired.

Photos table:

- id
- filename
- account_id
- created

Tags table:

- id
- tagname
- account_id
- category
- created

Photos_Tags table:

- photo_id
- tag_id

Photo.php

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tag' => array(
        'className' => 'Tag',
        'joinTable' => 'photos_tags',
        'foreignKey' => 'photo_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        //'with' => 'PhotosTag',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
```

Tag.php

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className' => 'Photo',
        'joinTable' => 'photos_tags',
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'photo_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        //'with' => 'PhotosTag',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
```

PhotosController.php

```
public function addtags($id = null) {
    $this->loadModel('Photo'); 
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        //$this->Photo->id = $id;
        if ($this->Photo->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The photo has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The photo could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Photo.' . $this->Photo->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Photo->find('first', $options);
    }
    //$this->request->data = $photo;
    $this->set('tags', $this->Photo->Tag->find('list'));
}
```

Photo edit form:

```
<div class="photos form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Photo'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Photo'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('account_id', array('type'=>'hidden'));
        echo $this->Form->input('filename');
        echo $this->Form->input('filename_th');
        echo $this->Form->input('desc');
        echo $this->Form->input('Photo.Tag' , array('label'=>'Tags', 'multiple'=>'checkbox'));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

print_r($this->request->data) :

```
Array
(
[Photo] => Array
    (
        [id] => 156
        [filename] => front_door_1
        [desc] => 0
        [account_id] => 1
        [user_id] => 
        [created] => 
    )

[Account] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [account] => ABC Bank
        [created] => 2014-06-17
        [modified] => 2014-06-17
    )

[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 
        [username] => 
        [password] => 
        [first_name] => 
        [last_name] => 
        [role] => 
        [email] => 
        [ip_address] => 
        [activation_code] => 
        [account_id] => 
        [created] => 
        [modified] => 
    )

[Comment] => Array
    (
    )

[Tag] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 27
                [tagname] => front_door
                [keyname] => 
                [category] => feature
                [account_id] => 1
                [user_id] => 3557
                [created] => 2014-07-12 16:58:44
                [modified] => 
                [PhotosTag] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [photo_id] => 156
                        [tag_id] => 27
                        [account_id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 
                        [created] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 65
                [tagname] => Surrey_Branch
                [keyname] => 
                [category] => location
                [account_id] => 1
                [user_id] => 3557
                [created] => 2014-07-12 16:58:44
                [modified] => 
                [PhotosTag] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 32
                        [photo_id] => 156
                        [tag_id] => 65
                        [account_id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 
                        [created] => 
                    )

            )

    )

)
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days fiddling with this app I created brand new CakePHP app based on same database. This was same CakePHP version.  But voila the newly created CakePHP HABTM was working perfectly.

I could view photo tags in photo view and edit forms. I could add/remove tags from photos.

I have done a quick review of differences in code between these CakePHP apps and I just can't see any obvious differences.

I copied and pasted code and files from old app to new app folders including entire views, specialized controller and model code.

Can't say what the difference between them was.

The takeaway here is that a) the CakePHP HABTM worked perfectly with newly baked app, and b) if anyone else encounters similar problems, suggest you try quickly re-baking app.